VBA Code to activate the tab and and transfer data
I have to create a Lab Inventory workbook. There are 11 tabs including Master tab. The story is when new items come in, the user must enter the information into the Master Tab (Column A to G), and when the item is transferred to another lab, the person must enter rest of the information into Column H to M. The transfer lab name is selected from a drop-down menu in column "M". My requirement is when the person selects a lab name (Lab 01) from column “M”, specific data (Column A to G) from that row should be moved to the Lab 01 tab, and the same procedure should be followed when transferring items from Lab 01 to another lab.
I am not much knowledgeable with VBA. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me to write a VBA code for this. I found following code to use to activate the tab (Lab name) when selected from the column “M” but I don’t have any clue how to transfer data in the same time to the same tab. My spreadsheet is attached here.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("M3:M2000"), Target) Is Nothing) Then _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
End Sub

If any of you can help me with this would be much appreciated.
Many thanks
Yeshi
Master Tab:

Lab Page:


What happens when they fill the data out in a different order?  E.g., select lab first, then the other data is not submitted to the preferred sheet.

For data entry, a userform is typically helpful to control required fields so the Command Button submission will execute the activities when all criterion have been added.  You would make a double click event for a cell in your sheet to pull that data, start pre-populating a userform (and saving the row number), then ask for the additional data; once command button is clicked, it moved the row and its data, or fills in the missing info on the master and and value=value to the destination sheet..

Why not keep all data on a single sheet, where it can be more-easily reviewed/summarized etc ?  If you need to view any given lab's inventory then you can filter the sheet by that column.  Replicating the same layout/functionality across multiple sheets is just a lot more work and makes your complete dataset less accessible for reporting etc.

It is a pleasure to hear from you Cyril. Command button option is not the preferred option. The requirement is, when they select the transfer lab name from the very last column (Column "M" on the master sheet and column "O" on all other lab sheets), it should automatically move to the appropriate tab (the tab names refer to the lab names), and the data on that particular row should be copied and written to the appropriate tab.

Yes Tim, thank you very much and that's exactly what I was thinking Tim, but the team will need to deal with separate tabs for each lab, and data should be copied over when the chemical is moved between labs. Thank you very much & I greatly appreciate your assistance.
